# How co copy mysql database A to schema B?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have mysql server version 8 running in docker container.

Some times I would like to copy (just make fresh clone) database `wordpress` to database `wordpress_test`.

How can I do it without downloading data from server?

Right now I am exporting data `wordpress` using MySQL workbench into my local computer and then I am importing downloaded data from my computer into `wordpress_test`, but today I need to download 20gb.

```
SHOW DATABASES 

information_schema 
mysql
performance_schema
sys 
wordpress
wordpress_test
```

Answer (score 0):

First login to the docker container

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

If the new database is not existing yet, you have to create it

```
echo "create database new_db_name" | mysql -u <dbuser> -p<password>
```

Then simply backup and restore

```
mysqldump -u <user name> --password=<pwd> <original db> | mysql -u <user name> -p <new db>
```

Since this is a big DB try by separately executing BACKUP and RESTORE

**BACKUP**

```
mysqldump -u <user name> -p <original db> > database_backup_file.sql
```

**RESTORE**

```
mysql -u  database_username  -p <original db> < database_backup_file.sql
```